# Changing the whole part of a number with the decimal part

Tags: c++

(sorry for my english)

So I have this number, for example 15.40, and I have to change it to 40.15 (I don't want to do it with strings).
I tried to do something like this:

```
    float a = 15.40;
    float d;
    d = a*100;
    d %= 100;
    d * = 100;
    d += (int) a;
    d /= 100;
```

but I got this error on the 4th line (`d %= 100;`) saying:

> error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'
>
> error:   in evaluation of 'operator%=(float, double)'

Can I do something about this, or I should stick to strings? Thanks.

Comment: `%` does not work with floating point numbers.  Why do you not want to do this with strings?

Comment: check:  http://cpp.sh/6pbkm for code that does it without string

Comment: Just want to learn and try new things. Thanks.

Comment: @Masoud This is what I was searching for. Thanks!